# Why malloc and sbrk returns address from seperate segments?

Tags: c, malloc, sbrk

I am trying to implement understand how dynamic memory allocation is happening. So I thought of implementing malloc of my own using `sbrk()` system call.
My Question here is when i try to allocate dynamic memory, sbrk() and malloc() returns different addresses not continuous.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\nsbrk(0) %llu ",(unsigned long long)sbrk(0));
    printf("\nmalloc(8) %llu ",(unsigned long long)malloc(8));
    printf("\nmalloc(8) %llu ",(unsigned long long)malloc(8));
    printf("\nsbrk(8) %llu ",(unsigned long long)sbrk(8));
    printf("\nmalloc(8) %llu ",(unsigned long long)malloc(8));
    printf("\nmalloc(8) %llu ",(unsigned long long)malloc(8));  
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above code is

```
sbrk(0) 30306304 
malloc(8) 30306320 
malloc(8) 30306352 
sbrk(8) 30441472 
malloc(8) 30306384 
malloc(8) 30306416
```

Can anyone explain why `sbrk(8)` is not continuous locations.

Comment: Modern POSIX allocators usually use [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) for their allocations, not `sbrk`.

Comment: By the way, the proper [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format to print a pointer (`void *`) is `"%p"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard does not give any guarantee for the contiguity of storage ***even for*** memory allocated by successive calls to `malloc`. So the different calls to `malloc` in your code need not yield contiguous locations.

The C11 standard states:

> **[7.22.3 Memory management functions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3)**
>
> [1.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3p1) The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to the
>   `aligned_alloc`, `calloc`, `malloc`, and `realloc` functions is unspecified.

And the addresses that come from the mixing up of `malloc` and `sbrk` calls need not be contiguous either.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're running on Linux, the reason the memory from `malloc()` and `sbrk()` has a relative large difference in location is that the glibc `malloc()` implementation uses `sbrk()` internally to obtain the memory that functions such as `malloc()` return to the caller.  For example, assume the initial internal glibc implementation obtains 32 MB of heap memory via `sbrk()` and memory returned from `malloc()` will be in this 32 MB chunk.  If you then use `sbrk()` to obtain memory, it will be from memory newly allocate at the end of that original 32 MB chunk, so the addresses from `malloc()` and `sbrk()` will differ.

Note that you can't safely mix the use of `malloc()` (and `calloc()`, `realloc()`, etc) and `sbrk()` since the internal implementation of `malloc()` uses `sbrk()` to obtain the memory it returns via `malloc()`.  Per [the Linux `malloc()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html):

> Normally, `malloc()` allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the
>          size of the heap as required, using `sbrk(2)`.  When allocating blocks
>          of memory larger than `MMAP_THRESHOLD` bytes, the glibc `malloc()`
>          implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping
>          using `mmap(2)`.  `MMAP_THRESHOLD` is 128 kB by default, but is
>          adjustable using `mallopt(3)`.  Prior to Linux 4.7 allocations
>          performed using `mmap(2)` were unaffected by the `RLIMIT_DATA` resource
>          limit; since Linux 4.7, this limit is also enforced for allocations
>          performed using `mmap(2)`.

When you mix `malloc()` and `sbrk()` on Linux to obtain memory, you will likely corrupt the process's heap.